# SAPUI5 using variables from control for View

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I wanted to ask if its possible to use a variable used in the Control of a certain View, to for example determine if a Control should be shown or not.

I.e. :

In the Main.controller.js:

```
],function(Controller, UIComponent) "use strict"; var oRouter; var enabled = true; ...
```

And in the Main.view.xml:

```
<filterbar:FilterGroupItem visibleInFilterBar="{enabled}" ...
```

I havent found anything, maybe Im searching the wrong keywords.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Generally, that is done through a JSONModel, have a look at the [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/topic/c72b922fdb59422496661000165d7ff1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Step 7: JSON Model](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/topic/70ef981d350a495b940640801701c409) in the "Walkthrough" tutorial.

For example, in the Main.controller.js:

```
    ... "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel" ],
function(Controller, UIComponent, JSONModel) {
  "use strict"; 

  return Controller.extend("com.work.mockserver.controller.BaseController", {
    onInit: function() {
      var viewModel = new JSONModel({
                       enable: true
      });
      viewModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay"); 
      this.getView().setModel(viewModel, "show");
    }
  }
}
```

in the Main.view.xml:

```
<filterbar:FilterGroupItem visibleInFilterBar="{show>enabled}" ...
```